# Flutter AwesomeNotification: How schedule a notification for several days of the week?

Tags: flutter, dart, awesome-notifications

I'm using the package `awesome_notifications 0.7.4+1` and I want to schedule a notification for several days of the week (for example on Monday and on Wednesday). I thought that the `NotificationCalendar` is the way to go, but I only have the option to put an `int` after `weekday:` . My code example shows, how I wish it was implemented (but it isn't), so you can get a better idea of what I want.

```
schedule: NotificationCalendar(
  weekday: [1;3],
  hour: 1,
  minute: 1,
  timeZone: timezone,
  repeats: true,
)
```

I am aware that there is also the option to user `NotificationAndroidCrontab` but I want my app to work also for iOS.

Is it even possible or do I need to create separate notifications?

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up just making two instances for each days.

Comment: @Laurent Blanc did you find a solution or did you just schedule multiple notifications?